# view.datacontext changes after .net upgrade 3.5 -> 4.61

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am currently trying to upgrade an existing WPF application.
It uses mostly codebehind but they are switching gradually to a MVVM pattern.
So far they have implemented MVVM in code by the following construct:

`//code located in codebehind of the ParentView
var childViewModel = new ChildViewModel();
childViewModel.Initialize(BusyWatcher); 
var childView = new ChildView { DataContext = childViewModel}; ContentPresenterParent.Content = childView;`

This has worked for them, they could bind to the childViewModel properties in the view by using for instance

```
Text="{Binding ChildViewModelProp1}"
```

Now we have upgraded the solution from .net 3.5 to 4.6.1 (upgrading to 4.0 has the same behaviour) we find the following behvaviour.

Although we are setting the datacontext on the childView to be the childViewModel, and this seems to be done correctly as observed when stepping through the code, the DataContext seems to get reset to itself (the childView). This seems to be done without triggering the DataContextChangedEvent.

This is evident by looking at Snoop and also in the output window we receive the following error:
BindingExpression path error: 'ChildViewModelProp1' property not found on 'object' ''ChildView' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=ChildViewModelProp1; DataItem='ChildView'

**What could cause the DataContext to get overridden/reset and why was this behaviour introduced by migrating from .net 3.5 to 4.6.1 (or to 4.0)?**

A workaround for this behaviour could be to bind xaml to

```
Text="{Binding DataContext.ChildViewModelProp1}"
```

But this is not really a nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There problem is the ContentPresenter, when you set the DataContext it changes it back to the Parent DataContext of the parent control. Here is more on the problem.

More can be found on the problem here.
https://alexfeinberg.wordpress.com/2014/10/11/wpf-the-real-difference-between-contentcontrol-and-contentpresenter/

Comment: Thanks juanvan, this indeed seems to be situation. Switching out the ContentPresenter with an ContentControl seems like an elegant fix. Still weird the behaviour changed by migrating to a higher .net framework.